# Not able to revert back to 8.1 after updating 10 insider preview

Tags: 8.1, insider-preview, lumia-520, windows-10-mobile, recovery-tool

I upgraded my Lumia 520 to windows 10 Insider preview. Now the phone hangs a lot and its getting too slow. It also displays message of low storage space even there is lot of space left (about 3.12 gb) on the divice.

Now I have decided to revert back to 8.1. I tried resetting to factory, hard reset and even I tried the Windows Device Recovery Tool. WDR tool shows the same version on server which is installed on my device which is "Firmware Version: 3058.50000.1425.0001" saying You have the latest available software version.

Even though I tried to reinstall, the download process is never completed. It starts and then after reaching about 8 percent, it stops saying there is error in downloading.

Can any one suggest a **full-proof way** to downgrade windows 8.1 from 10.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's resolved. The windows device recovery tool is downloading with resumes so I tried again and again whenever the download stopped and somehow finished the download and after reinstalling I am able to revert back to 8.1.

Comment: So you just reinstalled the same version and next time recovery tool showed 8.1?

Comment: Yes! The firmware version is the same but it reverted back to windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

The only way to revert to 8.1 is by using either the Windows Devices Recovery Tool or (since this is still a Nokia phone) you could try the [Nokia Software Updater for Retail](http://www.mediafire.com/download/5g4iqpbelwwpu6e/NokiaSoftwareUpdaterForRetail_4.3.2.exe) - that one worked for me when I got the sad smiley error on the Lumia 830.

A hard reset will never downgrade your phone, just reset all settings and delete all files.

Comment: I downloaded Nokia Software Updater (Ver 4.3.2) and installed in on pc. But on running it, it throws error : Could not check application update and there are 2 option available as buttons : exit and try again. On trying again, nothing happens and same error gets back. I am on windows 10 Pro PC.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a re installation will help you, but as u said it is not completing in your computer.So .
you can try these things:

1. Check if your network is fast enough to download the recovery image.and try re-installing the win recovery tool - might help.
2. Check the connection of your phone if it gets disturbed you'll not be able to download the image.
3. u can do the upgrade through the mobile insider app, select the windows 10 slow preview while doing from the app(you'll have less bugs)

Note: If u have the latest windows 10 in your phone, u cannot revert back to win8.1 - So please post the version of the windows u have in your phone.

Best

TSdcr.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the URL  http://www.windowscentral.com/roll-back-windows-phone-81-windows-10-preview

you can download the "Windows Phone Recovery Tool" and do it

Comment: I have already stated that Windows Device Recovery Tool is not able to download the required firmware.

Comment: I am perfectly done the window 10 insider to 8.1 update for that steps.
but i don't know what your facing exact issue. or simply you can do go care center they will help you